# What am I doing wrong in this game?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take up my first scripting language: python. I'm currently making a little game where you guess a predetermined number from 1-100. It also tells you if the right answer is bigger or smaller. Currently my code always returns that the right number is smaller, while it is not.

edit: thanks a lot for helping me!

```
import random

print("this is a game made by Sven")
print("you're supposed to guess the right number. it is between 0 & 101.")
print("lucky for you, you're getting hints.")
print("succes!")

rightnumber = (random.randint(1, 100))
print(rightnumber)

gok = int(input("type your guess here and press enter"))

def compareguess():
    if gok > rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")
compareguess()

def guessAgain():
    int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))
    compareguess()
    if rightnumber == gok:
        print("that was it! you won!")
    else: guessAgain()


if rightnumber == gok:
    print("that was it! you won!")
else: guessAgain()
```

Comment: When you take the input again: ```int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))```, you don't assign the value to anything. So ```gok``` remains the same and it is always bigger or smaller

Comment: Thanks, i updated that line to
``` gok = int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))```
however, i still get the same result.

Comment: Read about [scopes and namesspaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `gok` as a parameter to avoid global variables.

The problem is:

When you take the input again: `int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))`, you don't assign the value to anything. So `gok` remains the same and it is always bigger or smaller

```
import random

print("this is a game made by Sven")
print("you're supposed to guess the right number. it is between 0 & 101.")
print("lucky for you, you're getting hints.")
print("succes!")

rightnumber = (random.randint(1, 100))

gok = int(input("type your guess here and press enter"))

def compareguess(gok):
    if gok > rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")
compareguess(gok)

def guessAgain():
    gok=int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))
    compareguess(gok)
    if rightnumber == gok:
        print("that was it! you won!")
    else: guessAgain()


if rightnumber == gok:
    print("that was it! you won!")
else: guessAgain()
```

Also, don't use recursion. Instead, use a `while` loop. A shortened code without recursion:

```
import random

print("this is a game made by Sven")
print("you're supposed to guess the right number. it is between 0 & 101.")
print("lucky for you, you're getting hints.")
print("succes!")

rightnumber = (random.randint(1, 100))
while True:
    gok = int(input("type your guess here and press enter"))
    if gok > rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
        break
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
import random

print("this is a game made by Sven")
print("you're supposed to guess the right number. it is between 0 & 101.")
print("lucky for you, you're getting hints.")
print("succes!")

rightnumber = (random.randint(1, 100))
print(rightnumber)

gok = int(input("type your guess here and press enter"))

def compareguess(gok):
    if gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
    elif gok > rightnumber: 
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")
compareguess(gok)

def guessAgain():
    gok = int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))
    compareguess(gok)
    if rightnumber == gok:
        print("that was it! you won!")
    else: guessAgain()


if rightnumber == gok:
    print("that was it! you won!")
else: guessAgain()
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem

Comment: sorry I didn't see the entire code now i have updated it now it is working properly

Comment: The updated code looks similar to mine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the scope of the parameters. The first guess is stored globaly in `gok`. Whether it is smaller or bigger, `compareguess` will print a correct message.
But when you call `guessAgain` you don't save the new guess anywhere, so the value of `gok` is still the old one. Even if you would save it, the scope wouldn't be correct so you won't see the new value in `compareguess`.

So a possible solution would be to pass `gok` as a parameter to `compareguess` (I also added `rightnumber` as a parameter).

```
def compareguess(gok, rightnumber):
    if gok > rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")
```

And would now run -

```
while rightnumber != gok:
     gok=int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))
     compareguess(gok, rightnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

your `compareguess` functiuon

```
def compareguess():
    if gok < rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :) ")
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger. ")
```

your `guessAgain` function

```
def guessAgain():
    global gok
    gok = int(input("try again. type your guess and press enter."))
    compareguess()
    if rightnumber == gok:
        print("that was it! you won!")
    else:
        guessAgain()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this.
It keeps asking until you type the correct number.

```
import random

print("this is a game made by Sven")
print("you're supposed to guess the right number. it is between 0 & 101.")
print("lucky for you, you're getting hints.")
print("succes!")

rightnumber = random.randint(1, 100)
print(rightnumber)

def guess():
    gok = int(input("type your guess here and press enter: "))

    if gok > rightnumber:
        print("wrong! the right number is smaller :)")
        guess()
    
    elif gok == rightnumber:
        print("WOW! you guessed right!")
        print("that was it! you won!")
    
    else:
        print("wrong! the right number is bigger.")    
        guess()

guess()
```